# NodeJs returned array from database query is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined

An NodeJs app we are wrting has a problem with the query data returned as an array being `undefined`. I cannot find an exact match for our issue.

The following test case reproduces the problem. It is something to do with the calling function not waiting for the called function to finish? I'm not a JavaScript expert, and this behaviour does not make sense to me.

themod.js

```
module.exports = {

   getData: () => {
      let dbc = require('./mods/db.js');
      dbc.query(`

         SELECT 1 rn, 'One' rt UNION
         SELECT 2 rn, 'Two' rt UNION
         SELECT 3 rn, 'Three' rt ;

         `,
         function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
              console.log ( ' Error 1: ' , err );
            } else {
               arows =  module.exports.getSubData();
               console.log ( 'arows.length: ', arows.length );
            }
          })
   },

   getSubData: () => {
         let dbc = require('./mods/db.js');
         dbc.query(`

         SELECT 10 rn, 'Ten' rt UNION
         SELECT 20 rn, 'Twenty' rt UNION
         SELECT 30 rn, 'Thirty' rt ;

         `,
         function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
              console.log ( ' Error 3: ' , err );
            } else {
               console.log ( 'arows: ', rows.length );
               return( rows );
            }
          })
   }

}
```

theapp.js:

```
let tm = require('./themod.js');

tm.getData();
```

When it's run:

```
 node theapp.js
/path/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Query.<anonymous> (/path/node/themod.js:17:54)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/path/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (/path/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/path/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/path/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:149:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/path/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:133:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/path/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/path/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write /path/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/path/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
```

As requested, mods/db.js:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var dbConn = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'unam',
   password : 'pwrd',
   database : 'dbname'
});

dbConn.connect ( function(err) {
   if (err) {
      console.error( "DB Connect failed ", err);
   }
});

module.exports = dbConn;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem come from the scope of your **getSubData** function.

You do not return anything, you return row in the callback function but nothing at the **getSubData** level.
That's why arrow return null and then **.length** cannot be red.

You can try with this

```
   getSubData: () => {
         let dbc = require('./mods/db.js');
         return dbc.query(`

         SELECT 10 rn, 'Ten' rt UNION
         SELECT 20 rn, 'Twenty' rt UNION
         SELECT 30 rn, 'Thirty' rt ;

         `,
         function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
              console.log ( ' Error 3: ' , err );
            } else {
               console.log ( 'arows: ', rows.length );
               return( rows );
            }
          })
   }
```

you will then get the full query and the result inside.

So regarding functions synchronization you are good it is more a matter of scope.
This example should work :

```
const function1 = () => {
    const function2 = () => {
        return 'something'
    }
    return function2
}
```

Your wrote

```
const function1 = () => {
    const function2 = () => {
        return 'something'
    }
    //nothing returned for function1
}
```

Comment: why the -1  ont his ?

Comment: Who knows why the -1, I hope it doesn't discourage you from helping as your help gave me the nudge to solve the problem.